# Why is the infinitive form of the verb used after "for" and the present simple after "before" in this example?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, present-tense, infinitives, present-simple

In the sentence below, why is the infinitive form of the verb used after "for" and the present simple after "before"?

> London is a beautiful place **for** *her to visit*, but she must go **before**
> *she dies*.

Comment: We are dealing here with two quite different words with different meanings., which 
 simply sound similar to one another. And the constructions are different. But I can think of instances where they might be used similarly.  "London is a wonderful place for a holiday, and she will go there before Christmas". Both words are followed by a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that sentence, "for" is a preposition, and "before" is a conjunction, so it's not surprising they have different forms following them.

The surprising part is that "for" is followed by a pronoun "her" *and then a verb "to visit"*. After a preposition, we normally expect only a noun.

In your sentence, "to visit" is an *adjunct* that tells us in what way London is a beautiful place for her. It's not part of the object "her". It's just added on later.